# HTml Select drop down list

Tags: html, select

I have a form with a select drop down list. This drop down list is used for different kind of searches on the database. So it appeares on different html pages. 
 The drop down list is getting bigger as the database is growing. For the moment, I have to change the drop down list on each html page of the website seperatly. 
Is there a possibility to create a basic list of options to which each html page can refer?

so I have

```
<form name=f1 type=post action='' >     
<select name="data"  >
<option value="KTaharqa">  Karnak Kiosque de Taharqa</option>
<option value="PPyl2">  Karnak Porte du 2e pylone</option>
<option value="PPyl4">  Karnak Porte du 4e pylone</option>  
</select>
<input type='submit' value='valider' ">
</form>
```

Each time the database gets bigger  an new option is added.

so for example I have to add

```
<option value="PEst">  Karnak Porte de l'Est</option>
```

But I need to do this on 10 html pages which takes a long time.

Comment: Generally you use a database and a programming language, but it is a rather broad subject to explain from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can if your server is running php or any other server-side language.

I.E : You create an empty php file with your "basic options" and include it this way :

`<?php>include "dropdownlist.php";?>`

Alternatively, you can use `require` if it absolutely needed by the page and prevent its execution should an error pop-up or a file is missing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK but how do I make the options from the dropdownlist.php appear in the html select

Answer (score 0):

### Yes...!!!

> There are a lot of possibilities through which you can attain your
>   task...

- You can add filters to collect only imported results from your database using `SELECT` statement.
- Alternatively you can add more constraints using clauses like `WHERE` and many more.
- To show your drop down list in a group-wise manner you should use `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: It'll be better if you wisely use queries rather than implementing `php` codes, this will really help you out in finding patterns in your results.